# ambiguity of this inequality involve big O?

Tags: probability, inequality, asymptotics

Concerning the statement.

" $ξ$ is sub-gaussian if an only if $E |ξ|^{p} = O(p)
^{p/2}$ as p → ∞,

so we can redefine the sub-gaussian norm of $ξ$ as
$|ξ|_{ψ2} = \sup_{p≥1}p^{−1/2}(E |X|^{p})^{1/p}$
."

Yet if i condier the first part of the statement, there exists real number K, s.t. $E |ξ|^{p} < Kp
^{p/2}$ for large p.
Then $ K^{1/p} > p^{-1/2}(E |X|^{p})^{1/p}$, so the LHS is supposed to be the sup we find for determining sub-gaussian norm, but this $K^{1/p}$ varies with p?  Where is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire expression $O(p)$ is being raised to the $p/2$ power, so you have an upper bound of $(Kp)^{p/2}$.